# How to write lagrangian terms related to only one variable in a semidefinite constraint?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I have a semidefinite problem as follows(which is nonconvex) 
\begin{alignat}{3}
&\min_{x_{un}} \min_{t,H,w} &&t+f( w)\cr
&\text{s.t.   }
&&\begin{bmatrix}
 K\odot H &1-Xg(w)+ c\\
(1-Xg(w)+c)^\mathsf{T} &t 
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \cr 
&&&X=diag([x_k,x_{un}])\in R^{n*n},\cr&&&(w\in R^n, f(w)\in R, g(w)\in R^n,K,H\in R^{n*n})
\end{alignat}

$f(w)$ is a convex quadratic and $g(w)$ is linear function of $w$.
I think it's correct to move optimization about $x_{un}$ to most inner problem. Is it correct?

Then how can I write Lagrangian and obtain the dual problem with respect to the most inner variable, i.e, $x_{un}$? My confusion is how to write Lagrangian terms related to two semidefinite constraints, because I don't want to write the Lagrangian terms related to the any other variable.

EDIT: After sometime, I think it may be incorrect to write lagrangian terms related to only single variable. Any hint or comment, Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't quite understand your question. The primal variable does not matter when you write the Lagrangian form, the constraint matters. For the positive-semidefinite constraint, you also need a matrix as the Lagrangian variable.
$$ \lambda=\begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_{11} & \lambda_{12}  \\
    \lambda_{21} & \lambda_{22}  \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$
And when you write the Lagrangian equation, use the trace term for the positive-semidefinite constraint. Suppose your constraint is $A \geq 0$,corresponding Lagrangian term should be:
$$Trace(A\lambda)$$ 
Hope this can help you.